# Cancel button on a form causing meteor to throw exceptions when redraw happens

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm struggling to get a cancel button work on a meteor form. There is some interaction between the button and the reactivity on the form that is causing exceptions.

I have a form with two buttons, some inputs and some check boxes. The check boxes trigger some more input fields to be shown/hidden (which is working fine).

The cancel button, if pressed **before** any check box is used works fine. Once a check box has been activated however the app blows up with an exception as soon as a checkbox is checked (but after the extra input fields have displayed).

```
> Exception from Deps recompute:
> Patcher._copyAttributes@http://localhost:3000/packages/spark.js?3a050592ceb34d6c585c70f1df11e353610be0ab:1797
> Patcher.prototype.match@http://localhost:3000/packages/spark.js?3a050592ceb34d6c585c70f1df11e353610be0ab:1552
> patch/<@http://localhost:3000/packages/spark.js?3a050592ceb34d6c585c70f1df11e353610be0ab:1364
> patch/visitNodes@http://localhost:3000/packages/spark.js?3a050592ceb34d6c585c70f1df11e353610be0ab:1320
> patch/visitNodes@http://localhost:3000/packages/spark.js?3a050592ceb34d6c585c70f1df11e353610be0ab:1321
> patch/visitNodes@http://localhost:3000/packages/spark.js?3a050592ceb34d6c585c70f1df11e353610be0ab:1321
> patch/visitNodes@http://localhost:3000/packages/spark.js?3a050592ceb34d6c585c70f1df11e353610be0ab:1321
> patch/visitNodes@http://localhost:3000/packages/spark.js?3a050592ceb34d6c585c70f1df11e353610be0ab:1321
> patch@http://localhost:3000/packages/spark.js?3a050592ceb34d6c585c70f1df11e353610be0ab:1334
> Spark.renderToRange/</<@http://localhost:3000/packages/spark.js?3a050592ceb34d6c585c70f1df11e353610be0ab:699
> LiveRange.prototype.operate@http://localhost:3000/packages/liverange.js?b3097d72d458e645fd4f0021c8ff5189abe8d98a:491
> Spark.renderToRange/<@http://localhost:3000/packages/spark.js?3a050592ceb34d6c585c70f1df11e353610be0ab:693
> withEventGuard@http://localhost:3000/packages/spark.js?3a050592ceb34d6c585c70f1df11e353610be0ab:162
> Spark.renderToRange@http://localhost:3000/packages/spark.js?3a050592ceb34d6c585c70f1df11e353610be0ab:692
> Spark.isolate/<@http://localhost:3000/packages/spark.js?3a050592ceb34d6c585c70f1df11e353610be0ab:925
> ._compute@http://localhost:3000/packages/deps.js?eba25ec453bb70e5ae5c2c54192d21e0e4d82780:183
> ._recompute@http://localhost:3000/packages/deps.js?eba25ec453bb70e5ae5c2c54192d21e0e4d82780:196
> .flush@http://localhost:3000/packages/deps.js?eba25ec453bb70e5ae5c2c54192d21e0e4d82780:288
```

All the digging I've done seems to indicate a problem with the HTML but I can't find it. I've eliminated all of the code in the form and replaced it to narrow down the problem to the cancel button.

The form code is

```
<template name="joinLayout">
<section class="content" >
  <div class="modal fade in show" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
    {{> joinLayoutInner}}
  </div>
</section>
</template>

<template name="joinLayoutInner">
<div class="modal-header">
  <h1>Thankyou for Joining Tradebase.</h1>
  <h3>Please fill in the information below.</h3>
</div>
<form id="joinForm" action="action" class="col-sm-10 form-horizontal" role="form">
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="joinEmail" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="joinEmail" placeholder = "Required">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="joinPassword" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="joinPassword" placeholder = "Required">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="joinPhone" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Phone</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="joinPhone" placeholder = "Required">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="joinSuburb" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Suburb</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="joinSuburb" placeholder = "Required">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="joinState" class="col-sm-2 control-label">State</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="joinState" placeholder = "Required">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="joinPostCode" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Post Code</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="joinPostCode" placeholder = "Required">
      </div>
    </div>
    {{#if joinTradie}}
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="joinTradeCat" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Trade Category</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="joinTradeCat" placeholder = "Required">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="joinLicNo" class="col-sm-2 control-label">License Number</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="joinLicNo" placeholder = "Required">
      </div>
    </div>
    {{/if}}
    {{#if joinStudent}}
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="joinCourse" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Course</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="joinCourse" placeholder = "Required">
      </div>
    </div>
    {{/if}}
    <div class="form-group well" id="joinWell">
      <label class="checkbox-inline input-lg">
        <input id="joinUserCheck" type="checkbox" value="user" name="role" disabled checked>User</input>
      </label>
      <label class="checkbox-inline input-lg">
        <input id="joinTradieCheck" type="checkbox" value="tradie" name="role" >Tradie</input>
      </label>
      <label class="checkbox-inline input-lg">
        <input id="joinSponsorCheck" type="checkbox" value="sponsor" name="role" >Sponsor</input>
      </label>
      <label class="checkbox-inline input-lg">
        <input id="joinStudentCheck" type="checkbox" value="student" name="role" >Student</input>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">  
    <div class="form-group">
     <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-5">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg pull-left">Join</button>
      </div>
      <div class"col-sm-5">
        <button type="button" id="joinCancel" class="bnt btn-default btn-lg pull-right">Cancel</button> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
</template>
```

and the associated js

```
Template.joinLayoutInner.events({
  'click #joinTradieCheck': function(e) {                                      
    console.log("Tradie checkbox clicked");                                    
    Session.set("joinTradieTag", (joinTradieCheck.checked?1:0));               
  },
  'click #joinStudentCheck': function(e) {                                     
    console.log("Student checkbox clicked");                                   
    Session.set("joinStudentTag", (joinStudentCheck.checked?1:0));             
  },
  'click #joinSponsorCheck': function(e) {                                     
    console.log("Sponsor checkbox clicked");                                   
    Session.set("joinSponsorTag", (joinSponsorCheck.checked?1:0));             
  }
});     

Template.joinLayoutInner.helpers({                                             
  joinTradie: function() {                                                     
    return Session.get("joinTradieTag");
  },    
  joinStudent: function() {                                                    
    return Session.get("joinStudentTag");                                      
  },  
  joinSponsor: function() {
    return Session.get("joinSponsorTag");
  }   
});   

Template.joinLayout.events({
 'click #joinCancel': function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();                                                        
    Router.go('loginPage');                                                    
  },  
  'submit #joinForm': function(e,t) {                                          
    e.preventDefault();                                                        
    console.log("Form Sumbitted");                                             
  } 

});
```

If I comment out the html line for the cancel button, everything works as expected. As soon as I put that button back in.. boom.

Any ideas please?

Comment: What's the deal with the `joinSponsorCheck.checked?1:0`? To convert a boolean to a 1 or 0, you can just use the unary plus operator, e.g. `+joinSponsorCheck.checked`.

Comment: maybe try putting the cancel button inside a {{#isolate}}...{{/isolate}} block?

Comment: That is very cool Cuberto, I didn't know about the unary+ being able to do that. #isolate didn't help flylib.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. Turns out to be a simple typo (again!!)

Missed an "=" sign after the class for the div containing the cancel button. Still positioned the button correctly but failed when the page re-rendered it seems.

Peter.